# stm32h7 sdmmc DATA problem

Tags: stm32, sd, sdio

Im trying to send data with sdmmc and i cant see anything happening in data line on oscio.
CMD and CLOCK working fine but data just doesnt reacting.
this is how clock and cmd looking like (no data appears):
[image: this is how clock and cmd looking like (no data appears)]

what am i sending is just data to FIFO register:

```
     MMC_HandleTypeDef hmmc1;
    __HAL_RCC_SDMMC1_CLK_ENABLE();    
    MX_SDMMC1_MMC_Init();
    SDMMC_PowerState_ON(hmmc1.Instance);
    hmmc1.Instance->DCTRL = (9 << 4) | SDMMC_DCTRL_DTEN;
    hmmc1.Instance->FIFO = 0x5555;
```

and my init function:

```
static void MX_SDMMC1_MMC_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SDMMC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SDMMC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SDMMC1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SDMMC1_Init 1 */
  hmmc1.Instance = SDMMC1;
  hmmc1.Init.ClockEdge = SDMMC_CLOCK_EDGE_RISING;
  hmmc1.Init.ClockPowerSave = SDMMC_CLOCK_POWER_SAVE_DISABLE;
  hmmc1.Init.BusWide = SDMMC_BUS_WIDE_1B;
  hmmc1.Init.HardwareFlowControl = SDMMC_HARDWARE_FLOW_CONTROL_DISABLE;
  hmmc1.Init.ClockDiv = 0;

      result = HAL_MMC_Init(&hmmc1);
//  __NOP();                                             // Add a breakpoint here, check result value


}
```

I just stuck with it, why it doesnt send anything to data line

Comment: Ignoring the SDMMC peripheral, and removing the SD card if possible, are you able to pull or drive the net high or low as a GPIO pin?

Comment: Is this a custom (your design) or demo board?

Comment: @Rodo yes its custom board, its working fine woth software mmc implementation.

Comment: @Attie yes im able to drive high and low with data pin configured as gpio. Also its no sd card connected